# Offset Path In Figma?

Tags: figma

I am trying to use the Offset Path in Figma. Same as we do in Adobe Illustrator, but I am not sure if we can use it in Figma or not. Please tell me if yes then how we can use the **Offset Path** in Figma.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the path a stroke, then outline it and remove the unnecessary side from it if necessary. This would give you the same result as offset path in Illustrator.

[image: Figma screenshot: a curved path with thin black stroke]

Give it a thick centered stroke with weight of 2x of what you want the offset to be. For example here the offset from the previous stroke would be 10px with the stroke of 20px:

[image: Figma screenshot: the same path with thick stroke]

Outline Stroke:

[image: Figma screenshot: menu search with “Outline Stroke” command selected]

Select the unnecessary side:

[image: Figma screenshot: selected inner part of the thick stroke vector]

Press Delete:

[image: Figma screenshot: resulting offset path, thin again]